# Mobilefirst Failed synchronizing application from the administration service

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I create a new project in MobileFirst 7.0, but as soon as I am deploying it into MobileFirst Development server it is giving me following error:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0081E: Failed synchronizing application from the administration service. This prevents the application from running. The reason is No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [adapters, applications, configProfiles, transactionId]. Please restart the application server after taking the proper corrective actions. [project MyProject]
No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [adapters, applications, configProfiles, transactionId]
[ERROR   ] Synchronize operation failed.
No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [adapters, applications, configProfiles, transactionId]
[ERROR   ] Result: MyProject: worklight///10.80.111.52: Runtime synchronization failed
[ERROR   ] MyProject: worklight///10.80.111.52: 2015-03-28T22:36:55.555Z: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [adapters, applications, configProfiles, transactionId]
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /MyProject [project MyProject]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] MyProject: worklight///10.80.111.52: 2015-03-28T22:36:55.774Z: null
[ERROR   ] RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [adapters, applications, configProfiles, transactionId]
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:522)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:134)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [adapters, applications, configProfiles, transactionId]
    ... 5 more
```

I am using Windows 7, Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and JRE 7.

Comment: What's this: "MyProject: worklight///10.80.111.52"? Did you make any configuration changes in your workspace related to MFP?

Comment: No I did not changed anything @IdanAdar

Comment: Okay, well I'm thinking your installation is not good. Make sure you're using Eclipse Java EE and make a fresh installation from the Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: Reinstalling it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, my initial thought was that the installed went bad.
Re-installation seemed to have resolved the issue, thus this is the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this when upgrading a project from v6.3 to v7.0.  I had already been using my MFP Studio installation to build other projects, so I was confident the installation was ok.

I created a second Eclipse Workspace.  I added the project to the new workspace and was able to build with no issues in the new workspace.

You may be able to resolve this issue without reinstalling MFP if you switch to a new workspace.