# Error starting mobilefirst JVM after installing ifix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

After installnig IFIX 7.0.0.0 IF201609291531 on our MobileFirst 7.0 server, we now get an error when starting the JVM (using WAS full deployment).

The log reads:

> ProjectSynchr E com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean sync FWLSE0081E: Failed synchronizing application from the administration service. This prevents the application from running. The reason is No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON]. Please restart the application server after taking the proper corrective actions. [project worklightchprod]
>                                    java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON]
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.invalidObjectException(OpenConverter.java:1415)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.invalidObjectException(OpenConverter.java:1419)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaSetters.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$ArrayConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:588)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1324)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$ArrayConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:588)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1324)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.fromOpenReturnValue(ConvertingMethod.java:129)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:161)
>                   at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:259)
>                   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.updateContent(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:173)
>                   at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:156)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON]
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1316)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaSetters.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1116)
>                   ... 19 more
>
> [1/30/17 19:41:02:258 GMT] 00000081 StatusMessage E StatusMessage createStatusMessage Synchronize operation failed.
>                                    java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON]
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.invalidObjectException(OpenConverter.java:1415)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.invalidObjectException(OpenConverter.java:1419)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaSetters.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$ArrayConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:588)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1324)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$ArrayConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:588)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1324)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.fromOpenReturnValue(ConvertingMethod.java:129)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:161)
>                   at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:259)
>                   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.updateContent(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:173)
>                   at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:156)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON]
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1316)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.fromNonNullOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:915)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.fromOpenValue(OpenConverter.java:122)
>                   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderViaSetters.fromCompositeData(OpenConverter.java:1116)
>                   ... 19 more

We are using:

- Websphere 8.5.5.0 (+IBM HTTP server)
- Windows 2012R2
- MySQL 5.6.24

Our method was:

- Install ifix 7.0.0.0 IF201609291531 (using IM 1.8.1000.20141126_2002)
- Redeploy runtime
- Start JVM
- error appears

What we've tried to do to solve the issue

- Stop/Start MySQL
- clear WAS cache and start JVM

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your installation might be corrupted.  Try to install the Studio or create a new workspace and import your projects into this new workspace.  These workarounds were suggested here:
[Mobilefirst Failed synchronizing application from the administration service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323484/mobilefirst-failed-synchronizing-application-from-the-administration-service)

Answer (score 0):

We've resolved this issue by reinstalling the entire configuration, and redeploying the WAR file (runtime). This is not an ideal solution at all, but it's all we've got right now. Any advice on a proper resolution would be greatly appreciated